# How to find odd/even number without arithmetic operators in C?

Tags: c

How to find if a given number is odd/even without using `%`, `/` or bitwise operators?

Comment: What is the motivation for this ? Homework ? Interview question ? Something else ?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Any even number contains either of `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` as its last digit. Take an array, place this number and try to figure out what would be the next step.

Comment: I think @haccks motivation is enough.Now OP should try coming up with something.This should not be answered directly.

Comment: @PaulR; *Do you consider shift operations (`>>` and `<<`) to be "bitwise" ?*: It doesn't matter whether he consider it as bitwise operator or not, standard consider them as bitwise operator.

Comment: If I had ever seen or read of any processor without bitwise, boolean logical instructions, I would not down/close vote.  So, down it goes..

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an int is 32 bits:

```
bool even(int x) {
    return !(((unsigned int)x)*0x80000000);
}
```

This works by shifting all bits except the least significant out of the 32 bits of the int, so after that you have `0x80000000` for odd numbers or `0` for even numbers. This is converted to a `bool` and negated.

---

As Paul R points out int a comment, a portable version would use `INT_MIN` instead of `0x80000000`

Comment: This is very machine specific. These days most CPUs have 64 bits in an int ...

Comment: @haavee: actually [most 64 bit systems are LP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models), where `int` is still 32 bits.

Comment: You're right. But it doesn't make me like the answer any better, unfortunately.

Comment: @haavee: well it's easily fixed if you want to make it portable - just define the magic factor at compile time based on the width of an int. The general principle is sound.

Comment: I'd say the point of a decent algorithm is that you _don't_ change it for other sizes of `int`.

Comment: @haavee: it's an easy fix - just change `0x80000000` to `INT_MIN` - happy now ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @PaulR.

Comment: @haavee: Concerning " These days most CPUs have 64 bits in an int": Most processors these days are embedded devices using 32, 16 or even 8 bit data paths and registers - billions each year.  Suggest 100x more sub 64-bit processors built in 2015 than 64-bit ones.

Answer (score 1):

Division is nothing but repeated subtraction:

```
bool even(int number) {
    // INT_MIN in 2's complement is always even
    if( number==INT_MIN )
        return true;
    else if( number<0 )
       number = -number;
    while( number>1 )
       number -= 2;
    return number==0;
}
```

Comment: Did he say *without arithmetic operators*?

Comment: No, nothing about arithmetic operators. Negative or positive was also not mentioned but should be easily fixable.

Comment: The title and the question are inconsistent - the title says "arithmetic" but the question says  "%, / or bitwise operators". OP needs to sort out their question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yes. All too often the problems are ill formulated on SO :-(

Comment: Should you care for a non-2's complement specific code: `if( number < - INT_MAX) return true;`